# How to convert .heic to .jpeg from Google Form before uploading into Google Drive using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, jpeg, google-forms, heic

This is my first time programming with Google products so please bear with me.

I created a Google Form that accepts photos as file input and places them in Google Drive in a target folder determined by the form responses.

I started with this resource:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/upload-files#code.gs

My current code works fine, placing the images in the correct target folder.

I would like to convert .heic files to .jpeg so all devices can open the files.  I am trying to use the function **getAs("image/jpeg")** for the conversion.

If I leave out the getAs() function, the .heic files get placed in the correct target folder.

When I use the getAs() function, the .heic file is placed in the default **Files (File response)** folder but no .jpeg is created and nothing is put in the target folder.

Note that once I figure out how to do that, I will use an if/else statement to apply the conversion to .heic files only.

Thanks in advance for your help!

...

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  // Get the destination folder
  var destFolder = folder_based_on_form_response;  // this part works

  // Get all form responses
  let itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();

  // Get the file upload response as an array to allow for multiple files
  let fileUploads = itemResponses.filter((itemResponse) => itemResponse
    .getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD")
    .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
    .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

  // Move the files to the destination folder
  if (fileUploads.length > 0) {
    fileUploads.forEach((fileId) => {
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getAs("image/jpeg").moveTo(destFolder);
    });
  }
}
```

...

Comment: Have you checked your executions to see if there are any errors or warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert `.heic` format to Jpeg format by modifying your script.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, the following flow is used.

1. Detect `.heic` file.
2. Convert `.heic` format to PNG format.
3. Convert PNG format to JPEG format.
4. Create the image data in the JPEG format in the destination folder as a file.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```js
if (fileUploads.length > 0) {
  fileUploads.forEach((fileId) => {
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getAs("image/jpeg").moveTo(destFolder);
  });
}
```

##### To:

```js
if (fileUploads.length > 0) {
  fileUploads.forEach((fileId) => {
    const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    const name = file.getName();
    const mimeType = file.getMimeType();
    if (name.includes("heic") || name.includes("heif") || mimeType == "image/heic") {
      try {
        const url = `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=${fileId}&sz=w1000`;
        const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob().getAs("image/jpeg");
        destFolder.createFile(blob.setName(name.split(".")[0] + ".jpg"));

        // file.setTrashed(true); // If you want to remove the original file, please use this.
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e); // If an error occurs, you can see it in the log.
      }
    } else {
      file.moveTo(destFolder); // or file.getAs("image/jpeg").moveTo(destFolder);
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run when the file is `.heic` file, the `.heic` file is converted to Jpeg format and moved to the destination folder.

#### Note:

- When I tested this script using sample `.heic` files, no error occurs. The `.heic` files could be converted to Jpeg format and moved to the destination folder. But, if your `.heic` files are files that cannot be converted, an error occurs. please be careful about this.
- This script requires an "On Form Submit" installable trigger.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up simplifying the if statement to `if (mimeType == ("image/heic") || mimeType == ("image/heif"))` and it works perfectly!